# Performing Server Action Wihout User Input On Websocket

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, websocket

So I have a websocket server setup and running in PHP (CodeIgniter to be exact, though that shouldn't matter...). What I would like to do is have the server run "clean up" functions every n seconds without the use of CRON jobs if at all possible. Basically, I want the websocket server function that is already running to check for users that haven't done anything in x amount of time and "kick" them automatically by closing their socket.

From what I've seen all over the web, the only way to perform a server action is once user input is received...there isn't a way to run a server function automatically...

Ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "have the server run "clean up" functions every n seconds without the use of CRON jobs" ... is like saying, I want to drive nails, but I don't want to use a hammer...

Comment: @Brad the tool for this task is obvious and available, why not use it?

Comment: @jondavidjohn, Chances are, you don't want CRON firing off fresh copies of your script if the old one is still running, and that status may not be easily available to your script.  It also seems to me to be inefficient to startup PHP and a fresh copy of your script every few seconds, when you can just use a running instance.  Finally, if you daemonize it, you can easily start it and stop it with its own script in init.d.

Comment: @Brad Exactly right. I already have the script running on the server, why would I want to start up another? I'm certain there is a way to do this, I just can't for the life of me figure it out!

Comment: Did you read the answer I posted?

Comment: I did, and I am looking into it, but I would hate to have to use a PEAR plugin if I could just integrate something with the socket server "listener" that I have...you know?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to do this would be implement a daemon.

Here is a tutorial and a great class to get you started:  http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/

I use this class on a few daemons that do similar tasks.  They run for weeks, and I don't have any trouble.  You do need to be mindful though of your memory usage.  Make sure you don't have any anonymous functions that never get killed off by the garbage collector, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know anything about your "socketserver" but it sounds like a server writen in java, or somthing similar, and I'd assume that you have either written it yourself (or at least have the source). What you could do is start a thread running something like the following (this is writen in php, because I don't know java very well)

```
while(true) {
$oldTime = time();
while(time()-$oldTime < 10) continue;
clean();
up();
functions();
}
```

Comment: The server is written in PHP and has a very similar while(true) loop in there, but it is to handle changed sockets (aka new data being sent in, new connection, disconnect, etc.). What I want to have happen is have the server run functions while there isn't anything coming in since no "ping" gets sent to the server. Does that make zero sense?

Comment: why would you write a server in php? and if i understand what you said, you want to run the functions when no traffic is detected perhaps like this:
while(true) {
while(check_for_connections()) {
functions();
} 
}